# sentence meaning “My car is having new tyres fitted.”

Tags: sentence-meaning

> My car is having new tyres fitted.

My guess is as follows

The above sentence means

> I am having new tyres fitted on my car.

Is *My car is having* a "firm intention / definite decision"? or "arrangement in the future"?

Comment: To make it syntactically and idiomatically unambiguous you might want to add "as we speak" or "tomorrow at 10" or "before the first snow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in American English, this is syntactically ambiguous.  The phrase "is having" can be present progressive or future tense.  I might say "my car is having new tires fitted" while my car is presently at the shop and someone is changing its tires, or when I have an appointment to have them changed next week.  The present progressive is more likely with no further context; if I don't tell you when it is happening, it's probably happening now.

It's possible that this is different in the dialect of English your tyres are from.